# Why Array.push apply and call not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am don't understand why this code not work. Here a.push.apply(this, b); and a.push.call(window, 7); no works too.

```
<script>
        var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        var b = [7];

        a["push"].apply(this, b);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are "applying" `push` to the wrong object. Try:

```
<script>
        var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        var b = [7];

        a["push"].apply(a, b);
</script>
```

Same reasoning for `a.push.call(a, 7);`.

`a["push"]` only gives you a function back with no information on the invocation object. When you call apply you are applying the function, what you need to do is to provide an "object context", that is the object on which you want to apply the function, and the function parameters.

Comment: Works! Why it works? first argument is object context, i thought it may be anything

Comment: For clarity: it might as well be (and is often written as): `Array.prototype.push.apply(a, b)` to avoid this confusion. When written as this it is clear that the function being applied is not associated with any object implicitly.